# spring data jpa not updating the record

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working with the spring-boot , spring data jpa, I have a scenario like get the record and update state of the record.

```
  Project updateProject =null;
    private void changeStatusOfProject(Integer projectId, String statusJobSchedule) {
        logger.info("changeStatusOfProject "+STATUS + statusJobSchedule);

        Project p =projectDao.findOne(pid);

        updateProject = new Project();
        updateProject.setProjectId(p.getProjectId());
        updateProject.setPText(p.getPText());
        updateProject.setEcommDisplayFlag(p.getEcommDisplayFlag());
        updateProject.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
        updateProject.setUpdatedBy("Chandu");

        logger.info("p id : " +p.getpID());

        if (statusJobSchedule.equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")) {
            updateProject.setActive("N");
        } else {
            updateProject.setActive("Y");
        }
        updateProject.setExecutionStatus(statusJobSchedule);

        projectDao.save(updateProject);

    }
```

I am not getting a exception either.

---

trail 2:

projectDao is implementation class of jparepositarty

```
private void changeStatusOfProject(Integer projectId, String statusJobSchedule) {
        logger.info("changeStatusOfProject "+STATUS + statusJobSchedule);

        Project project =projectDao.findOne(projectId);



        if (statusJobSchedule.equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")) {
            project.setActive("N");
        } else {
            project.setActive("Y");
        }
        question.setExecutionStatus(statusJobSchedule);

        questionBankDao.save(project);

    }
```

Comment: i trust projectDao is actually projectRepository in spring? Then your active JPA object is p, not updateProject. You are likely getting a primary key constraint voilated while trying to create a new project object and its throwing a unchecked exception

Comment: "I am not getting a exception either", then what are you getting? Also, can you explain what `updateProject` is and why it is not within the method? Is it a field? And what is `projectDao`? Without more information, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: what was your exact question? as @g00glen00b said without more info, this question cannot be answered

Comment: i am getting record in the same method , and updating but update is not happening.. , no exception nothing , What information you need @jai

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a while back and for me it was because it was being cached.

I fixed it by adding `@Cacheable(false)` to my entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Am not seeing any error on your code, but try in this way

```
 private void changeStatusOfProject(Integer projectId, String statusJobSchedule) {
    logger.info("changeStatusOfProject "+STATUS + statusJobSchedule);
    Project p =projectDao.findOne(pid);
    p.setUpdatedDate(new Date());
    p.setUpdatedBy("Chandu");
    logger.info("p id : " +p.getpID());
    if (statusJobSchedule.equalsIgnoreCase("Completed")) {
        p.setActive("N");
    } else {
        p.setActive("Y");
    }
    p.setExecutionStatus(statusJobSchedule);
    projectDao.save(p);
}
```